# Multiple Server Actions in Odoo 8

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm adding a new server action to my Odoo, but is not working ok. It's supposed to check the n selected items, but only is checking the first one. What I'm missing?

[image]

[image]

XML

```
<record id="action_server_validate" model="ir.actions.server">
    <field name="name">Validate / Unvalidate</field>
    <field name="type">ir.actions.server</field>
    <field name="model_id" ref="model_account_voucher"/>
    <field name="binding_model_id" ref="model_account_voucher"/>
    <field name="state">code</field>
    <field name="code">
        for obj in object:
            obj.validate_invalidate()
    </field>
</record>
```

Python

```
class AccountVoucher(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'account.voucher'

    validated = fields.Boolean('Validated', default=False)
    payment_mode_id = fields.Many2one(related='payment_line_ids.payment_mode_id')

    @api.multi
    def validate_invalidate(self):
        for rec in self:
            if not rec.validated:
                rec.validated = True
            else:
                rec.validated = False
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`object` is a record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None (In your example above it should be the last item)

You probably couldn't use `records` because of the following error:

```
 ValueError: "name 'records' is not defined
```

The available [locals](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/addons/base/ir/ir_actions.py#L570) are:

- **time, datetime, dateutil**: Python libraries
- **env**: Odoo Environement
- **model**: Model of the record on which the action is triggered
- **object**: Record on which the action is triggered if there is one, otherwise None
- **workflow**: Workflow engine
- **Warning**: Warning Exception to use with raise

To call the function on all selected records, you can pass `active_ids` to the `validate_invalidate` function like the following :

```
self.validate_invalidate(cr, uid, context.get('active_ids', []), context=context)
```

Or:

```
model.browse(context.get('active_ids', [])).validate_invalidate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your XML code

from

```
for obj in object:
    obj.validate_invalidate()
```

to

```
records.validate_invalidate()
```

And you can remove the else condition from the *validate_invalidate()* function. You have already provided a default value for it.

Comment: Hi Bhavesh. I don't know if it's because of odoo version but im having this error with records          -          ValueError: "name 'records' is not defined" while evaluating
u'records.validate_invalidate()'

Comment: Is it Odoo 8? Correct? I think from your screenshot and create button & other UI, it seems like openerp 7.0 version.

Comment: Yes mate, is Odoo8

Comment: It should work in Odoo 8. Other try: Can you try with `objects.validate_invalidate()`? 
The issue is from the XML side, your code sending only 1 recordset instead of selected. You can pass `active_ids` in the context to get it in .py function.

Comment: I'm trying to do it but isn't possible, could you provide some example of how to use active_ids?